# App running fine in debug mode with breakpoints in the code but gives unexpected results while running normally in windows phone 7.5

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, windows-phone-7, geolocation

I am experiencing a weird issue in which my app runs perfectly fine when there is a breakpoint on any of my code lines but gives unexpected results when launched without any breakpoints. Basically I am using a GeoWatcher to get location and then getting weather information of that place. I have also placed Messagebox to verify that my required code executes and it does but doesn't complete the desired functionality it supposed to do. This is the code which needs to be executed for my case but is not executing properly in normal mode.

```
     Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                                {
                                    IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CurrentLocationAdded"] = true;
                                    obj.Start();
                                    RetrieveFormatedAddress(obj.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString(), obj.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString());
                                }));
```

Kindly if anyone could help me resolve this. I shall be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
    {
        IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings["CurrentLocationAdded"] = true;
        obj.Start();
        RetrieveFormatedAddress(obj.Position.Location.Latitude.ToString(), obj.Position.Location.Longitude.ToString());
    });
```